# Xamarin Pass Data Between Activity

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I can not share data between 2 activity:

Activity1

```
homeButton.Click += delegate {
    var second = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondPage));
    second.PutExtra("reg", "qwe");
    StartActivity (typeof(SecondPage));
    }
```

Acitvity2(SecondPage)

```
string txt = Intent.GetStringExtra ("reg") ?? "null";

Console.WriteLine (txt);
```

Still get null, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a start, you should pass the intent you created:

```
homeButton.Click += delegate {
    var second = new Intent(this, typeof(SecondPage));
    second.PutExtra("reg", "qwe");
    StartActivity (second);
    }
```