# How pass data between two android views?

Tags: android, android-activity, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I have a simple application that needs to do the following:

1. From the main view the user clicks a button that launches another view.
2. The new view is displayed and collects information from the user.
3. Once the user clicks OK on that new view I need to "send" that data back to the originating view.

The problem I am finding is that once I use StartActivity (with an intent) or SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main) is that my data is gone. I'm putting the information I collected in a global variable but when I get back to my originating view its being recreated.

How can I pass this data back to the originating view so that I can update some UI controls?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xamarin Pass Data Between Activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096523/xamarin-pass-data-between-activity)

Comment: @aleckz don't forget check the correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

Have you tried startActivityForResult. I'm guessing that is what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var activity2 = new Intent (this, typeof(Activity2));
activity2.PutExtra ("MyData", "Data from Activity1");
StartActivity (activity2);
```

More information about how this works here:
http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/

Answer (score 0):

You must call startActivityForResult with the intent and implement the onActivityResult for capture the info that come from Class2.

Activity Class1:

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, Class2.class), 1);

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // do something
   }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
```

For send the info to Class1 you must call setResult with the info in your bundle and call finish().

Activity Class2:

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("---your info---");

    setResult(RESULT_OK, new Intent().putExtras(bundle));
finish();
```

Read the section "Starting Activities and Getting Results" from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: And what is the proper way to "return" to Activity 1? Is that what setResult does?

Comment: SetResult is the call that do that, but you must call finish after to terminate de Activity Class2 and return the Bundle to Class1

Comment: You must call Class2 with startActivityForResult from Class1

Comment: you got some advance?